# Nexus 3 create clean up policy with Groovy script

Tags: groovy, nexus, nexus3

I want to create a cleanup policy for maven and docker repositories on nexus 3 with Groovy.
All the solutions and examples I've found so far are cleanup scripts and cleanup tasks.
I want with Groovy to create a cleanup policy, attach it to repository(maven or docker) and create a task to run periodically with that policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: This the new solution. The 1st groovy script creates and attaches a policy to a Docker repository and the 2nd groovy script is creating the Docker repository

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.cleanup.storage.CleanupPolicyStorage

def createPolicy (policyName) {
    try {
        def policyStorage = container.lookup(CleanupPolicyStorage.class.getName())
        def cleanupPolicy = policyStorage.newCleanupPolicy()
        cleanupPolicy.setName(policyName)
        cleanupPolicy.setNotes('')
        cleanupPolicy.setMode('deletion')
        cleanupPolicy.setFormat('docker')
        cleanupPolicy.setCriteria(['regex': '.*SNAPSHOT'])
        policyStorage.add(cleanupPolicy)
    } catch (e) {
        log.info("Cleanup policy already exists, skipping...")
    }

}

def attachPolicy (policyName, repositoryName) {
    try {
        def repo = repository.repositoryManager.get(repositoryName)
        def cleanupPolicyAttribute = [policyName: [policyName].toSet()]
        def conf = repo.getConfiguration()
        conf.getAttributes().put("cleanup", cleanupPolicyAttribute)
        repo.stop()
        repo.update(conf)
        repo.start()
    } catch (e) {
        log.info("Attaching policy fail")
    }
}

createPolicy('dockerCleanupPolicy')
attachPolicy('dockerCleanupPolicy', 'docker-NameOfTheRepo')
```

With this script we are creating the repository. Keep in mind that in older nexus version you should import `import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.WritePolicy` instead of `import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.config.WritePolicy`

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.api.BlobStoreManager
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.config.WritePolicy

def createDockerHosted(repoName, repoHttpPort){
    try {
        repository.createDockerHosted(repoName, repoHttpPort, null, BlobStoreManager.DEFAULT_BLOBSTORE_NAME, true, false, WritePolicy.ALLOW)
    } catch (e) {
        log.info("Repo already exists, skipping...")
    }
}
createDockerHosted('docker-NameOfTheRepo', 5001)
```

Old solution
Found it, this is an example of how you do it

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.cleanup.storage.CleanupPolicyStorage;
def policyStorage = container.lookup(CleanupPolicyStorage.class.getName());
def cleanupPolicy = policyStorage.newCleanupPolicy();
cleanupPolicy.setName('name');
cleanupPolicy.setNotes('');
cleanupPolicy.setMode('deletion');
cleanupPolicy.setFormat('raw');
cleanupPolicy.setCriteria(['lastBlobUpdated':'432000']);
policyStorage.add(cleanupPolicy);
```

Comment: This creates a cleanup policy correctly. But in order to consume this policy we have to add this to a repository. Any idea how to add this policy to a repository?

Comment: @U.Ahmad I've updated my answer with creating a Docker Repository on Nexus & creating-attaching a policy to a Docker repository. I hope I could help.

Comment: How can we define in this function to remove component that were published over x days ago(component age) and same for component usage?